# What is the difference between ‘truemm’ and ‘mm’ etc.?

Tags: lengths, dimensions

Sometimes I see the use of `truemm` (or `true mm`) instead of `mm` (same for other units). So I’m wondering what is the difference between these? Or: Why are some units *false*?

Comment: Where did you see it? In LaTeX or plain TeX files?

Comment: @egreg: Hm … good question … I have no specific file in mind. But the given answers already answer my question :-)

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=true+%5Blengths%5D

Comment: I tried `true [dimensions]`, and that tag was missing in the question … I added it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No one says it better than Knuth ([TeXbook](http://ctan.org/pkg/texbook), Chapter 10: Dimensions, page 59).

> When you say `\magnification=2000`, an operation like
>   `\vskip.5cm` will actually skip 1.0 cm of space in the final
>   document. If you want to specify a dimension in terms of the final size,
>   TeX allows you to say `true` just before `pt`, `pc`, `in`, `bp`,
>   `cm`, `mm`, `dd`, `cc`, and `sp`.  This unmagnifies the units, so that the
>   subsequent magnification will cancel out. For example, `\vskip.5truecm`
>   is equivalent to `\vskip.25cm` if you have previously said
>   `\magnification=2000`. Plain TeX uses this feature in the
>   `\magnification` command itself: Appendix B includes the instruction
>
> ```
> \hsize = 6.5 true in
> ```
>
> just after a new magnification has taken effect. This adjusts the line width
>   so that the material on each page will be 6½ inches wide when it
>   is finally printed, regardless of the magnification factor.
>   There will be an inch of margin at both left and right,
>   assuming that the paper is 8½ inches wide.

Comment: Thanks … I guess it’s time to finally buy and read the book myself …

Comment: @Tobi If you don't the additional markup, you can read the TeXbook from source.  I linked it in the question.

Comment: Jep, I know that the source I public but I like printed books :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can set a magnification with \mag, it is not often used in latex packages but plain has a \magnification macro build on it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\mag 2000
\begin{document}
\rule{10truemm}{10truemm} 
\rule{10mm}{10mm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the example code! I accepted Henri’s answer since it has more explanations (and he has less reputation `;-)`)

Comment: @Tobi Having less rep shouldn't be the reason for accepting my answer.  You should accept the best one!

Comment: @HenriMenke: I know ;-)